# How do I undo torch.unique_consecutive?

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I efficiently revert [torch.unique_consecutive](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique_consecutive.html#torch.unique_consecutive)? I.e.:

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2])
output, counts = torch.unique_consecutive(x, return_counts=True)



y = torch.SOMETHING(output,counts) #y equals x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [torch.repeat_interleave(**args)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html) for your task

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2])
output, counts = torch.unique_consecutive(x, return_counts=True)
y = torch.repeat_interleave(output, counts)
#>>y = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```